# MudBlazor WASM project hanging on startup

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I want to set up a new WASM project using MudBlazor and I am following the [instructions](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation) on their documentation but as soon as I get to step three adding

`<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js" />`

my project won't start any more. It just says loading ...

I followed the instructions to the letter and I tried it twice but everytime on Step 3 it fails. Am I doing something wrong or are the instructions wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there was an error on the documentation which has since been corrected. The correct line is of course

`<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>`

If you change it to this it will work. I have tested it.